# Module Not Found Error: No module named 'listings.settings'

Tags: python, django

Just starting out with Python and Django. I built this app that is basically a really simple real estate listing website. Everything is coded out and based on a tutorial I just went through, as far as I can tell everything matches. I've gotten this to work before so I'm a little confused as to what is going on. Here are two images of the error I'm getting and my file structure.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are you creating subfolder listings of listings?

Comment: Why your manage.py file is inside your folder's app? It's suppose to be in the main directory.

Comment: Figured it out thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the error by moving the items of listings(subfolder) to listings(parent folder).
This error is raised because Django is looking for settings.py inside the listings folder(parent folder).